# Add metadata to .gpx tracks recorded with OsmAnd

Tags: gpx, tracking, osmand

Using OsmAnd app to record gps tracks allows to collect the data listed [here](https://www.osmand.net/docs/user/plugins/trip-recording#recorded-gpx-file).
Is it possible to add some more data, such as the name of te user or the type of vehicle? If it is not possible to do it within the application is it possible to add data later, maybe directly modifying the .gpx file with a text editor?

Comment: If you don't find a solution with osmand there are several online tool that let you edit gpx file.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's certainly possible to edit the GPX file in a text editor

Comment: What file format should the result be in, what do you need it for? Does it have to be a gpx file?

Comment: @Babel, no need to change the extension, but to add info other than the ones usually stored in a .gpx file, especially concerning the tracks (for instance, in addition to the _name_ and the _time_ one could add also the vehicle used for that track, or the activity was involved in).